# Import classes without file name

Tags: javascript, oop

In javascript is it not possible to import a class without having to refrence the page. This seems ugly to me.

I have a class called "DashboardPage"  It is located within a file name called "DashboardPage.js".

In order for me to import the class, I have to export the class in the file and then import it in another file. Like so

```
module.exports.DashboardPage = DashboardPage;//Export

var DashboardPage = require("DashboardPage");//Import
```

Now when I want to create a new DashboardPage. I have to go:

```
//Here is the problem. Why do I have to call the file name then the object. 
var page = new DashboardPage.DashboardPage();
```

Am I doing something silly here? This seems silly. I come from a C# background and I may be going at this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have to do anything with class in JavaScript but with the CommonJS module system.

`require` simply returns the value that is assigned to `module.exports`. So you can also export a value by directly assigning to `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = DashboardPage;
```

Then when you do

```
var DashboardPage = require("DashboardPage");
```

`DashboardPage` is already your class and you create a new instance by calling `new DashboardPage()`.

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your answer. One more question, perhaps you know the answer.


var LoginPage = new require("LoginPage");
var Page = new LoginPage();


The two lines of code i supplied above, is it possible to put them into one line of code? 

Kind of like

var page = new required("LoginPage")();????

Comment: Yes. You can always substitute a variable with the expression that produced the value assigned to the variable.